# ONTouch event issues?

Tags: iphone

Touching anywhere on screen the user should go to the next view in iphone application?
How can we implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can Make use of this method of touches

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Get all the touches.
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    //Number of touches on the screen
    if([allTouches count] > 0)
    {
//Navigate to next screen here likewise you generally do
    }
else
{

}

}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Read [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details

For now you can implement the

> - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

method in your viewController class and load the otherViewController possibly by pushing over NavigationController.